# Get Headers response in php

Tags: php, header, response

i viewed Inspect Element at tab headers have section Form Data :

```
In Form Data section:
isslverify:true
iagent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:22.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/22.0
ihttpheader:true
url:https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B2_6BBaiKDFLYlBVR1QwUko0UHc/edit?pli=1
```

how to get this informations in php code.

thankyou!

Answer (score 4):

```
print_r(get_headers($url));
```

this will print all the header relate data

http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-headers.php

Answer (score 0):

you have to use [get_headers](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-headers.php) php function:

```
// set the url you want to get the headers
$url = 'http://www.example.com';

// print out the headers on a non-associative array
var_dump(get_headers($url));

// build it up an associative array
var_dump(get_headers($url, 1));
```

Comment: oh thankyou. but it no working in my ask. my mean get in Form Data. your solution haven't url item.

Comment: array (size=7)
        0 => string 'HTTP/1.0 200 OK' (length=15)
        1 => string 'Date: Wed, 30 Jul 2014 08:16:57 GMT' (length=35)
        2 => string 'Connection: close' (length=17)
        3 => string 'Vary: User-Agent' (length=16)
        4 => string 'X-LiteSpeed-Cache: hit' (length=22)
        5 => string 'X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.10' (length=24)
        6 => string 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8' (length=38)

Comment: this is my Inspect Element: https://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/931x247q90/743/AVsdod.png